# How to make Greek-containing tokens in minted, without XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Tags: minted, greek

I would like to use mixed Latin/Greek tokens (variable names) like `helloδ` in [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted). To stay compatible with [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) I cannot use [XeTeX](http://xetex.sourceforge.net) or [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org).

Outside of [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted), working with [`textgreek`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textgreek) is my favourite way of getting good Greek characters. Is there a way to get the [`textgreek`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textgreek) characters into a [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) frame without using the `escapeinside` mechanism that interrupts the token lexing process? Here's a minimal example of what I *don't* want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted} 
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{mask}
hello|\textdelta|
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) has broken up the variable name into a Latin part and a Greek part. The fancyvrb line generating the above output is

```
\PYG{n+nt}{hello}\PYG{esc}{\textdelta}
```

Simply changing the appearance of `\PYG{esc}` to match the rest of the token is not a good solution because the token `helloδ` may appear in different settings and require different appearances throughout the text. I would much rather know how to generate

```
\PYG{n+nt}{hello\textdelta}
```

directly. Any other solutions are welcome too, of course.

Comment: That's most likely not a minted issue but a Pygments lexer issue. Maybe you should check what Pygments create and open an issue for Pygments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is neither `minted` nor `pygments`, but rather the TeXShop installation defaults. The solution is to set the first line (or any of the first 20 lines) in the .tex file to

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

to force the editor to handle the file in UTF-8. The details are in the TeXShop menu point "Help - File Encodings and TeXShop".

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}
δ
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{mask}
helloδ
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool so it can't be too hard! What is your setup? I'm using TeXShop on MacOS. When I copy-paste Greek characters from the Wikipedia into the .tex source (assuming they are proper Unicode) I just get question marks in the PDF.

Comment: I did run pdflatex from a current texlive on windows, the file itself is naturally utf8 encoded. The python is older - I seldom use python and so don't maintain it like I maintain my texsystems.

Comment: As Ulrike has shown, the problem was neither `minted` nor `pygments`. It is simply that by default TeXShop does not read UTF-8 properly. See my answer below. Danke Ulrike!